# Cmake get/query/print build settings on the command line?

Tags: cmake

Let's assume I have a Cmake C project, and I have something like this in the project:

```
project(my_project C CXX ASM)
set(my_executable_sources
    main.c
    file_one.c
   )
set(my_executable_sources ${my_executable_sources} file_two.c)
add_executable(my_executable
               ${my_executable_sources}
               file_three.c
              )
```

Let's assume I'm in the `./build` subfolder, and `cmake ../ -G "Unix Makefiles"` has passed successfully.

Can I somehow query build information from the command line using `cmake`?

For instance, I'm interested here in the *final* list of source files for `my_executable`; is there a command that would easily retrieve them? Say, like the following pseudocode:

```
$ cmake --pseudo-query-build --project="my_project" --target="my_executable" --query="source_files"
my_executable source files:
main.c
file_one.c
file_two.c
file_three.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by obtaining the target's sources via this line (after `add_executable`):

```
get_target_property(MY_TARGET_SOURCES my_executable SOURCES)
```

And then proceed with a simple line at the end of the file (after `add_executable`)

```
message(STATUS ${MY_TARGET_SOURCES})
```

EDIT: For a full list of available target properties refer to [this link.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#target-properties)

EDIT2: As I've noticed now that you probably intend to just use it within the CLI, then for my solution you would also have to encapsulate it with a `if/endif` that checks for a `definition` e.g. `if(SOURCES_DEBUG_INFO)` and then run it with `-DSOURCES_DEBUG_INFO=TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any cmake-generator-independent way of achieving this and even if you know the generator in use the project files generated.

You could modify your project to include a custom target that prints the sources though:

```
add_custom_target(print_my_executable_sources COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:my_executable,SOURCES>" COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS)
```

this allows you to use

```
cmake --build <binary_dir> [--config <configuration>] --target print_my_executable_sources
```

to print the sources, even if generator expressions are used in the sources.

Note: This does print all files in a single line; to get all the file names on separate lines, you could instead run cmake with the `-P` option passing the soures via `-D` and add logic to print one file name per line in the cmake script file.

---

Alternatively setting the [`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) variable to `True` during configuration could result in the generation of json files that would allow for the extraction of the information, but you'd need a json parser to extract the info. Furthermore this approach only works for the Makefile and Ninja CMake generators. Also I'm not sure you can tell which target a source file belongs to in all cases.